# CSS Canvas or Div element that is centered, maintains aspect and covers the screen?

Tags: html, css

Trying to find an elegant CSS way that maintains an aspect ratio for a Div (or a canvas) element and at the same time covers the screen and keeps the div centered.

Suppose we want the div to be 16:9, but if the screen is too narrow allow the div width to extend beyond the screen left and right (crop) by an equal amount while filling 100% of the height. Do the opposite if the screen is too wide.

(Kind of simulate the `object-fit:cover` property for images, but do so for the div element itself)

Comment: please share your code with us

Comment: @XenioGracias I am not sure how to approach this. I don't have any code to share.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would be one solution for this.

You'll want a `height` of `100vh` on the container (to cover the full height of the page), along with `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.

Then all you need to do is specify a fixed `width` and `height` on the child element.

The element will always stay in the center, while also retaining its dimensions and aspect ratio. This can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the aspect of the container to be 16:9 at all times regardless of the aspect of the viewport, and it needs to cover the viewport. So the container cannot be 100vh because if the screen is (say) 20:9 then the container needs to be 100vw, and if the screen is (say) 10:9 then it needs to be 100vh.

Comment: If you need to maintain aspect ratio then really your only option is *fixed* units like above. Regardless of your screen size, the square will always be 10 by 100 -- you can always adjust that to suit. It's outright *impossible* to have a static aspect ratio taking up 100% of a *variable* viewport. But you can *cut* some of it if need be, by using `overflow`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with after toying with it for a little while.

There seems to be a way to do this using min-max for making the element cover the screen and then use @media to center it.
In my case the desired aspect ratio for the canvas element was 105:50
(The canvas element contains a webGL animation that we want centered while the browser window resizes)

```
#IndexPageCanvas {
   z-index: -1;
   position: fixed;
   min-height: 100vh;
   max-height: 47.6vw;
   min-width: 100vw;
   max-width: 210vh;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 105/50) {
   #IndexPageCanvas {
      left: calc((-210vh + 100vw)/2);
   }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 105/50) {
   #IndexPageCanvas {
      top:calc((-47.6vw + 100vh)/2);
   }
}
```